# Arguments for a BroadcastReceiver used inside Intent.createChooser()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have many share buttons on my App. When a share button is pressed, a chooser is showed to the user so he can select an app to share the content. I wanted to know what the user chose so I decided to use a `BroadcastReceiver` with the `Intent.createChooser()` method.

But I have multiple share buttons across the app, so I defined the following class:

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver(val listener: MyBroadcastReceiverListener) : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        listener.handleShare()
    }

    interface MyBroadcastReceiverListener {
        fun handleShare()
    }
}
```

I want to use this class from different places that implement `MyBroadcastReceiverListener` (Activity1, Activity2, Activity3, etc.) so I can perform the corresponding task on `override fun handleShare()` at each place. The problem I'm facing is that I have to do this before using the `Intent.createChooser()`.

```
var receiver = Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java) // how can I pass args  ?
var pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
Intent.createChooser(..., ..., pi.getIntentSender());
```

Because I have to provide `MyBroadcastReceiver` in a static manner, I can't pass arguments (listener in this case) to `MyBroadcastReceiver`. Is there a way to address this problem? Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Story:** To run a block of code after users choose an app from the app chooser dialog. You shouldn't pass your activity as a listener because this can leak the activity (the application might keep a reference to the activity even it got destroyed).

**Solution:** Using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to achieve your goal.

**Step 1:** Add EventBus to your project via gradle

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
```

**Step 2:** Defines events

```
object OnShareEvent
```

**Step 3:** Register/unregister listening event from your activity, such as Activity1.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun handleShare(event: OnShareEvent) {
    // TODO: Your code logic goes here
}
```

**Step 4:** Post events

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(OnShareEvent)
    }
}
```